# Selected Line feature to Buffer in Model Builder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder

How can I Create a model in arcgis model builder for Select one road(Line) from Road network and then create a buffer for that particular line feature.
there is a big road network and we want to select one particular road(Line) and then create a 100m buffer for that in ArcGIS Model...???[image]

Comment: The question is how do you want to select one line? If you can define it either spatially or by attributes then use Make Feature Layer (with where clause) or without and use Select Layer by Location for spatial queries. Selection made in ArcMap are valid in model builder if you are having trouble, select manually in ArcMap then run your model.

Comment: You need to expand on this more. What's your selection criteria (ie select by attribute or location), then buffer by x..

Comment: I want it select by attribute, and then create a buffer only for that particular Line or object in arcgis Model .

Comment: @JaikSingh As we ask for clarifications it is best to use the **edit** to keep updating your question to address them.  There is no guarantee that potential answerers will read any of the questions so the idea is to keep all the important information in your question and to make that as clear as possible.

Comment: @GISI - I'm thinking Select tool followed by Buffer to avoid also having to Make Feature Layer

Comment: Jack, put the snapshot of what you have done so far

Comment: file:///C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/admin/Desktop/model.JPG       .......But there is no method to select a line and create buffer for that...Here the problem is How can I select one feature set from our line network and then create a buffer, only selection procedure is missing..........................file:///C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/admin/Desktop/model.JPG

Comment: By snapshot I mean upload the snapshot of the model within model builder, you have created so far

Comment: @PolyGeo, your comment sounds like an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are so close to the answer but in your comments you have mentioned your need to select that line based on attributes and not spatial criteria. As Michael and PolyGeo answered your questions in the comments, You can use **Select** from Analysis toolbox or Make Feature Layer (with where clause) to select that specific line and then buffer it.

Here is the final model:

[image]

Put your selection criteria in Expression Box:

[image]